# How can I create call an async method inside another async method without it stalling

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5, async-await

I need to call multiple async methods and inside of them, call another async method aswell.
Let me demonstrate

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
    {
        await Method1();
    }
}

public async Task Method1()
{
    await Task.Delay(3*1000);
    await Method2();
}

public async Task Method2()
{
    await Task.Delay(10*1000);
}
```

My problem is, the for statement only activates the iterations after the wait on Method2 starts and what I want is to create the 100 Task all at once. Everything else will be done asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `await`-ing each tasks as you create it in the for loop, you just want to start all of the tasks.  You don't want to delay the scheduling of the next task until the previous finished, so just don't `await`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
    {
        var task = Method1();
    }
}
```

Done.

If it's important that you do something after all of the tasks finish, while still doing all of them in parallel, then you can rely on `Task.WhenAll` to generate a task that will be completed when all of the other tasks are done:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Method1());
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    textbox1.Text = "Done!"; //or whatever you want to do when they're all done
}
```

Comment: I think you should almost always `await` the `task`. With your first snippet, if there is an unhandled exception in `Method1()`, it will just silently go away, which I think is a very bad thing.

Comment: Your answer led me to the solution, although it wasn't exactly the way you said. Thanks

Comment: @svick There are lots of ways of handling exceptions.  Without knowing what you plan to do if one is thrown it's hard to suggest a solution.  You could add an onerror continuation, you could ensure that errors are handled within `Method1` rather than from the caller (wrapping it in another method just to handle exceptions if that's needed), etc.

Comment: @jure Why would you want to do that? The method is asynchronous, so starting it in parallel isn't likely to give you any performance improvement.

Comment: @Svick I'm not very experienced with parallel programing. Never had the need to use a lot of parallel processing, so this is more of my question. Is starting 100 tasks as Servy proposed in one for loop same thing as starting it with Parallel.For?

Comment: @jure It's not exactly the same thing, the behavior will be somewhat different. But starting an `async` method (which is what calling it does) usually doesn't take long, so it's not worth parallelizing it.

Comment: @Svick Thanks for clarification. I get that there is probable no sens in parllelizing async method... I was more wondering if there is any adavantage if the Method1 is not written as async and then the tasks for Method1 are started with Parallel.For. But thats probable material for a new question..

Comment: @jure If you did that then you would be blocking the UI thread.  You'd instead want to just have one (not 100) method that you fired off asynchronously and then had your parallel loop inside the body of that one method, although that wouldn't really be better than this code here, it's just what you'd need to do if you wanted to use `Parallel.For`.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are confused as to what "await" means. "await" means "start processing this thing asynchronously, and while that is ticking away, go back to the windows message loop and keep on processing messages so that the UI keeps on re-drawing.  When the asynchronous task is done, pick up the code where I awaited".

So when you `await` in a loop like that, you are saying:

- Start the first asynchronous job...
- and while it is running, keep processing the message loop.
- When the first asynchronous job is done...
- pick up in the loop where we awaited. We go around the loop and...
- Start the second asynchronous job...

If that's not what you want then *don't await the task*. If you want to start a hundred tasks that run concurrently then *start a hundred tasks and don't await any of them*. Why is there *any* await in the click handler?

Comment: What about exceptions? If you don't `await` the `Task` (or handle its result in some other way), any exception that happened during execution of the `async` method will be silently ignored.